# Using Array.from in Typescript received function is not defined error

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

I try to use some ES6 syntax in my Typescript app and want to change the for-of loop to Array.from when mapping an observable object array, but I received undefine is not a function error.

```
   Array.from(item.modules, ([value]) =>
       selectedImage.setModules(
        moudleWithThumbnail(value.name, value.version).name,
        moudleWithThumbnail(value.name, value.version).version,
        moudleWithThumbnail(value.name, value.version).thumbnail
    ));
```

but if I write in another way, it works fine

```
 const arr = Array.from(item.modules);
    arr.map((item: any) =>
      selectedImage.setModules(
        moudleWithThumbnail(item.name, item.version).name,
        moudleWithThumbnail(item.name, item.version).version,
        moudleWithThumbnail(item.name, item.version).thumbnail
      )
    );
```

I don't know what is the difference between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `([value]) =>`, you're destructuring the first iterable property of the parameter (an item) into a `value` variable name. But your `item` is an *object*, not an iterable (like an array) - so array destructuring syntax like `[value]` won't work.

If you wanted to destructure, use object destructuring instead, extracting the `name` and the `version`:

```
Array.from(item.modules, ({ name, version }) =>
  selectedImage.setModules(
    moudleWithThumbnail(name, version).name,
```

Or don't destructure:

```
Array.from(item.modules, (item) =>
  selectedImage.setModules(
    moudleWithThumbnail(item.name, item.version).name,
```

Or, an even better strategy to keep the code less repetitive would be to call `moudleWithThumbnail` only once (if doable):

```
 Array.from(item.modules, (item) => {
   const { name, version, thumbnail } = moudleWithThumbnail(item.name, itemversion);
   return selectedImage.setModules(name, version, thumbnail);
 });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really want to improve my code quality and you just give a better solution!